# Can't Flag as duplicate to facebook.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions

Under the flag dialog, 'Closing > Duplicate' on Stack Overflow will not allow me to enter a URL to Facebook Stack Overflow (facebook.stackoverflow.com). However, the same dialog on Facebook Stack Overflow allows me to enter a URL on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Because Facebook.SO is a subset of SO.

Comment: @RobertHarvey right, but the duplicate parser should probably be smart enough to find the "real" URL (just chop off facebook.) so people don't have to manually butcher URLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed; you can use either the main or subdomain question url on either site when  choosing the original of a duplicate.